# Why are HDMI switches much slower than VGA switches?

Tags: hdmi, vga, kvm-switch

I used to have a cheap VGA based switch. After pressing the button, it would take 1-2 seconds for the display to switch.

Later, I decided to use the more modern and more advanced HDMI standard. My cheap HDMI switch takes a full 7-8 seconds to switch the display.

Isn't HDMI supposed to be a better replacement for older technologies like VGA? Why is switching displays so much slower? Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: HDMI is a consumer spec structure. The real 'successor' to VGA [& DVI] is DisplayPort [Now built into USB-C on some devices].

Comment: When talking about something being "better" or "worse" you have to specify which properties you're comparing. HDMI will easily handle my 1920×1080 monitor with perfect quality, while VGA will be blurry. So in this aspect it's definitely better. But it may at the same time be inferior in other aspects. Reality is complex.

Comment: HDMI is DATA transmission for picture and sound, VGA is pure electronics for display rendering. The HDMI 1.0 version starts at some 4,95 Gbit/s. I'd guess interrupting and diverting the data stream might be slightly trickier than just flipping analogue wires over to a new destination.

Comment: @Tetsujin So DisplayPort would be able to switch faster?

Comment: Theoretically. Practically it may depend on your KVM.

Comment: What switch are you using? Do they have a stated specification noting how long it will take to switch? I know HDMI also handles a lot of data other than just video. Along with video there's also audio, networking, and USB I believe, depending on factors.